# Reports: Displaying "My Team" or a specific user

Tags: reporting, formula-field

I need to know how to enter in the filter of a report that I either (OR) want "My team's" opportunities" OR Opp ower= Andrea If I enter "My Teams" under Salesforce's premade filter then anything I add below become an AND statement to the initial "My Team's" filter